# How to compare two time range in Android?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time

I have two string variables "time1" & "time2". Basically, each string variable itself is a time range.
Either "time1" is in between "time2" **OR** "time2" is in between "time1". Print "Not Available".

**Example Case 1:**

```
String time1 = "14:00 - 16:00"

String time2 = "15:00 - 16:00"
```

*Print "Not Available"*

**Example Case 2:**

```
String time1 = "14:00 - 17:00"

String time2 = "15:00 - 16:00"
```

*Print "Not Available"*

**Example Case 3:**

```
String time1 = "15:00 - 16:00"

String time2 = "14:00 - 17:00"
```

*Print "Not Available"*

**Example Case 4:**

```
String time1 = "15:00 - 16:00"

String time2 = "14:00 - 16:00"
```

*Print "Not Available"*

**Example Case 5:**

```
String time1 = "14:00 - 15:00"

String time2 = "15:00 - 16:00"
```

*Print "Available"*

*There could be multiple cases like this.
Actually, "time2" refers to "Slot is already booked by another user during this time"and "time1" refers to "new user requesting slot during this time" 
P.S: Working on reservation system.*

Answer (score 2):

First, you parse the strings to find `startTime` and `endTime`, for each of them.

Since these are simple `hour:minute`, you can simply calculate those as minute-of-day, i.e. `hour * 60 + minute`.

A simple way to parse both start and end times, is using regular expression.

```
public final class TimeRange {
    private final int startMinOfDay;
    private final int endMinOfDay;

    public TimeRange(String text) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2}) - (\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        if (! m.matches())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid time range: " + text);
        this.startMinOfDay = minOfDay(m.group(1), m.group(2));
        this.endMinOfDay = minOfDay(m.group(3), m.group(4));
        if (this.endMinOfDay <= this.startMinOfDay)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid time range: " + text);
    }
    private static int minOfDay(String hour, String minute) {
        int h = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(minute);
        if (m >= 60 || h >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid time: " + hour + ":" + minute);
        return h * 60 + m;
    }
    public boolean overlaps(TimeRange that) {
        return (this.startMinOfDay < that.endMinOfDay && this.endMinOfDay > that.startMinOfDay);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("14:00 - 16:00", "15:00 - 16:00");
    test("14:00 - 17:00", "15:00 - 16:00");
    test("15:00 - 16:00", "14:00 - 17:00");
    test("14:00 - 15:00", "15:00 - 16:00");
}
private static void test(String time1, String time2) {
    System.out.println(new TimeRange(time1).overlaps(new TimeRange(time2)) ? "Not Available" : "Available");
}
```

*Output*

```
Not Available
Not Available
Not Available
Available
```